# T-SQL - Is there a (free) way to compare data in two tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sqlcompare

I have `table a` and `table b`. (SQL Server 2008)

Both tables have the exact same schema.

For the purposes of this question, consider `table a` = my local dev table, `table b` = the live table.

I need to create a SQL script (containing `UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT` statements) that will update table b to be the same as table a. This script will then be deployed to the live database.

Any free tools out there that can do this, or better yet a way I can do it myself?

I'm thinking I probably need to do some type of a join on all the fields in the tables, then generate dynamic SQL based on that.

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

Okay, thought I'd clarify this question a little.

The table I need to synchronize is a simple look-up table. The data is very simple and straightforward.

Here's an idea of what `TABLE A` might look like:

```
IdFoo          Activity      IsFoo
1              Foo           1
2              Bar           0
```

Here's an idea of what `TABLE B` might look like:

```
IdFoo          Activity      IsFoo
1              Foo           1
2              Bar           1
```

Basically, all I want to do is update that `BIT` column (`IsFoo`) in `TABLE B` to match the corresponding value in `TABLE A` for the same IdFoo.

Keep in mind:

- `TABLE A` is on my local machine
- `TABLE B` is on the live server

Obviously I have a (reliable) backup of `TABLE B` on my local machine which i need to script against, then run the script on the live server.

The table also has referential integrity (other columns I didn't show). Which means I can't just delete everything in `TABLE B` and do an insert from `TABLE A`.

This script will be a once off. So no need to do things like linked server, replication, etc. Appreciate the answers though guys. =)

**EDIT:**

Ok - so I've gone with Oleg's answer (VS2010 Data Compare). Quick, easy, and works a charm.

Not to say the other answers are incorrect. I appreciate all the answers!

Comment: Any answer would very much depend on the fact if you have a field that reliably can be used to match two rows.

Comment: The answer also depends on how often you need to do this and how large the data is?  If it is a one time thing you could just use the Import/Export wizard to transfer `table b` to `table a`.  If you want the changes to be reflected immediately and continuously you could implement Replication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In very simple cases you will be able to define in your local SQL Server a new Linked Server  (see in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio under "Server Objects" / "Linked Server") and use `INNER JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN` to find out differences between A and B tables.

In a real and more complex situation you should take into consideration Referential Integrity, different Foreign Keys, and Identity (auto incremental) fields existing in the destination database, so the update script will be more complex. So I'll recommend you don't spend your time in creating synchronization of your developer and production DB and use a standard tool instead. I use for example the features of Visual Studio Team Edition 2008 (or Database edition) or Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition to compare data in two databases. It works very well.

Comment: Ive got VS2010 - how do you compare data in two databases with that? Do you have a reference/link?

Comment: Just go in menu "Data" choose "Data Compare" and "New Data Comparison". Then choose source and destination databases and "Data Compare Options". Then follow the wizard. At the end you can examine comparing results, "destelect" some differences, and either write the reschanges directly in the destination database or generate a SQL Script. In the "Tool" "Options" menu you can chose some code generation options. You can not only compare data, but also compare schema of databases if needed.

Comment: Cool - ok ill give that a go tomorrow (when im back at work) and let u know how i go - cheers for the tip!

Comment: You can read more about Compare and Synchronize Data in Visual Studio 2010 under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193261.aspx. By the way if needed, you can automate Data Compare through DTE (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psirr/archive/2008/11/22/data-compare-dte-commands.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Late answer but can be useful to the thread visitors

Besides other mentioned solutions, I can suggest trying ApexSQL Data Diff. It can compare and sync SQL Server database data (in live databases as well as backups), and automate and schedule data migrations. It works with huge databases also, and is able to perform comparisons directly from SSMS.

You can download this tool for free and play with it. It features a fully functional free trial, and offers a community edition (after the trial period is over) that works on SQL Express and Azure SQL Database.

To learn more about the tool, you may visit http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to synchronise the tables and don't care about reviewing the changes in advance the [MERGE](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1704) command can do this.

[MSDN - MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.110).aspx)

The (free) Microsoft SSDT also has data compare and synchronization built in though it is more limited than paid tools such as Redgate data compare.

Answer (score 4):

There is [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) from RedGate (though not free) and there is also [SMO](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated) and the [built in](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) functionallity.

Finally [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_Compare_Tools) has quite a comprehensive list of software.

Comment: The RedGate SQL Data Compare tool isn't free. SMO is a good idea though, and the Wikipedia link is a great source.

Comment: Sorry Bernard I misread part of the question and somehow interpreted it as if free was preferred though optional, I've edited the answer to reflect that. Need more coffee I guess.

Comment: The wikipedia link now, annoyingly. just redirects to the main SQL Server page.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is one off, you can use this query to find rows that are different in this two tables:

```
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
 MINUS
 SELECT * FROM TABLE_B)

 UNION ALL

(SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
 MINUS
 SELECT * FROM TABLE_A)
```

`MINUS` will compare records field by field, then  it will discard records from first table for which there is identical record in second table.   This works like this:

- First `MINUS` gets all records from `TABLE_A` that are not in `TABLE_B`
- Second `MINUS` gets all records from `TABLE_B` that are not in `TABLE_A`
- Union gets all records from both tables for which there is no matching record in other table.

Now you can insert those records in some temp table and then do inserts/updates.

Depending on your needs, you can restrict field list for comparing.

Note that you need primary key for this to work.

**Edit:**
Ooops. SQL Server does not support `MINUS` operator. I'm working with ORACLE last year and half, so this was automatic.

You can use `EXCEPT` operator instead. See this article: [**EXCEPT and INTERSECT (Transact-SQL)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055(v=SQL.105).aspx)

**Edit 2:**

Re [scherand's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254868/scherand) comment:
If he really cannot connect from local machine to live server, than he can simply dump `TABLE_A` and load it on server. One way or the other, goal is to change table data on live server.

Comment: Interesting...never heard of the MINUS keyword. I'll give that a go also (and yes - the first column is a PK - identity).

Comment: That does not work, unless OP can define his/her workstation/live server as linked server (as @Oleg pointed out)...

Cite: "Keep in mind: TABLE A is on my local machine TABLE B is on the live server"

Answer (score 3):

I ran in the same problem as you - searched for a free tool that compares data from two MS SQL tables - and found nothing. Then I created a simple freeware command line utility. It compares data from two tables, and creates `INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE` statemenets to make destination table data the same as source. Now I am using it for data comparison, and as it is completely free, can recommend to check it out at: [Sourceforge.net - UltraDBC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zmcompare/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a data script generator that creates script for the inserts, and then use a file comparison tools such as WinMerge to compare the files to find the differences. There's an article on generating the data scripts on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlinsertupdategenerator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Tablediff would work - it's free and comes with SQL Server
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the  `import and export data` provided by SQL Server 2008. Its is fairly straight way to copy all the data from anywhere to anywhere. I do the same thing and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You might try our [Schema Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/)

This tool is not free (it's shareware), but you can use 30-days trial for free and also, you have an opportunity to get a free license for this product - please refer to our [free license conditions page](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/get-free-license.html).

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you:

1. copy devTableA onto prod,
2. suspend dependencies on prodTableB
3. rename prodTable B to prodTableB1,
4. rename devTableA to prodTableB
5. reimplement dependencies on new prodTableB
6. test new prodTableB and then delete out-named old prodTableB

?

or if you have to be more respectful of the existing prodTableB and your identity column values in both dev and prod match (even if the values are not continuous)...

```
declare @iLast int, @x int, @y int
select @iLast = (select MAX(id) from prodTableB)
set @x = 1
while @x <= @iLast
begin
  select @y = (select COUNT(*) from prodTableB where id = @x)
  if @y = 1
    begin
      update prodTableB set isFoo = (select isFoo from devTableA where id=@x
    end
  @x=@x+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [xSQL Data Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql). The SQL Express version is free and there is also a Lite version that will do the trick for small databases.

A good free tool is also data compare from [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx).

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with xSQL.